# Azure Functions - How to create a Custom trigger?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, cloud

I'm working on Azure.
In my scenario, I should create a new Azure function triggered by a process that in background polls for the change data capture of a PostgreSQL/Mongo database.
From the available triggers, there's no similar trigger between the available during the azure function creation.
So, is it possible to create a custom trigger ?
If the answe is yes, how is it possible and what is the language used?
Have you any other different idea about how this problem can be solved using a different Azure component?

Thanks for the help

Comment: @Iordav you can try using Azure SQL Trigger for Change tracking of your database refer here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp This SQL trigger binding is in preview

Comment: You can also use custom binding with .net framework and consume it with other languages refer this document - https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings

Comment: But using SQL trigger would be more efficient way here..

Comment: Thanks for you answer @SiddheshDesai. 
Only one question. Is it possible to use SQL Trigger with PostgreSQL and CosmosDB with Mongo DB API ?

Comment: AFAIK, The trigger as the name suggests only supports, Azure SQL and SQL server instance, If you want tp use cosmosdb you can use CosmosDB trigger refer here for the same - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cextensionv4%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: And postgreSQL is also not supported refer this Ms  Q & A answer here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/814083/azure-python-funvtion-with-postgresql

Comment: Bur you can connect your PostgreSQL with Azure Functions by referring this blog- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/connect-from-function-app-with-managed-identity-to-azure/ba-p/1517032

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I don't need to connect to a PostgreSQL instance from an azure function and I can't use the Azure SQL Trigger because it doesn't work for PostgreSQL and Mongo.
What I have to do is to use a custom trigger. How can I work with a custom binding without a custom trigger?

Answer (score 0):

First, use Debizium. - Debezium is an open source distributed platform for change data capture. (more info: https://debezium.io/)

On Azure, you can use Azure Event Hub: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.6/operations/debezium-server.html#_azure_event_hubs

Then, you can trigger your function from Azure Event Hub events.

The sample below is using Azure SQL Database, but it will give you some guidance:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sql-db-change-stream-debezium